# AWS user can access stuff I didn't grant them access to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I created an AWS user and granted them access to just a few things as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

And then they logged in and told me they can access my S3 and a few other services. I even had them test uploading a file to my S3.

So what did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the policy for AWSLambdaFullAccess. Under "Action" you will see "s3:*". This gives the user full access to all S3 commands. Under "Resource" you will see "*". This give the user full access to all resources (in this case all S3 commands on all S3 resources).